# Details on an anecdote about optimizing with boundary conditions (the highest point in Florida)

Tags: calculus, optimization, applications

Back in my undergraduate days, as a motivational example in real analysis for the importance of checking boundary conditions when doing global optimization, my professor related a story about how cartographers in Florida initially identified the highest point in the state incorrectly.

The story went that the office manager (or whoever) answered the problem by measuring all of the peaks in the state, then reporting back the height of the highest peak as the highest point in the state. But it turns out to fail because the highest point in Florida is on the border.

This appears to have some basis in fact (e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Florida%27s_highest_points) identifies Britton Hill as the highest point in the state, and it [certainly appears](https://www.google.com/maps/place/30%C2%B059'18.0%22N+86%C2%B016'55.0%22W/@30.9877509,-86.2873677,6646m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d30.988333!4d-86.281944?hl=en) to be near enough to the border with Alabama as to have been a potential foil), but I had trouble backing up the story itself (that the state had made some mistake initially in identifying the peak by only using local maxima). Unfortunately I don't know/remember any more details of the story that would help me track it down -- who exactly was to blame for the mistake, whether the mistake was ever actually published, when in time this is supposed to have happened, etc.

Is this story perhaps apocryphal?

Comment: As mathematicians, maybe we won't know it ourselves (especially since there are many non-Americans here, including myself). I'd suggest the [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/) for better results.

Comment: By searching in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?q="highest+point+in+florida"+calculus) and [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q="highest+point+in+florida"+calculus) you can find a few places where this is mentioned. However, I do not see anything which could be a supporting evidence that this mistake really appeared in literature.